# Matrix Algebra Proof: $\left(A^TB^{-1}\right)^{-1}=B\left(A^T\right)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices

I am having trouble proving the above equality using just the following assumptions:

1. $CC^{-1}=C^{-1}C=I$
2. $IC=CI=I$

Assume the inverse of A and B both exist and $I$ is the identity matrix. Also, matrix multiplication can be applied.

Comment: Also, C is just a generic matrix to demonstrate the two listed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one side,
$$
A^TB^{-1} = A^TB^{-1} 
$$

$$
A^TB^{-1}B = A^T B^{-1}B = A^T
$$

$$
A^TB^{-1}B(A^T)^{-1} = A^T(A^T)^{-1}=I 
$$
and from the other side

$$
A^TB^{-1} = A^TB^{-1} \to (A^T)^{-1}A^T B^{-1} = IB^{-1} = B^{-1}\to
B(A^T)^{-1}A^T B^{-1} = BB^{-1}=I,$$

hence, 
$$
(A^TB^{-1})^{-1} = B(A^T)^{-1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the general rule $(CD)^{-1} = D^{-1}C^{-1}$ when both are invertible. You can check this easily by multiplying by $CD$ on either side.

Comment: I am aware of this rule.  But I need to prove it using the listed properties.  I cannot use the other one.

Comment: It's the identical proof.

Answer (score 0):

This results from a general fact on general rings with identity:

> If $a,b$ are invertible in the ring $R$ with identity $1_R$, $ab$ is
>   invertible, and $$(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$ Indeed we have
>   $$(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=a(bb^{-1})a^{-1}=1_R.$$

Furthermore, one has $\;(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$.

Another fact on rings of matrices:

> If $A$ is an invertible matrix in $\mathcal M_n(R)$, its transpose is invertible, and $$({}^{\mathrm t\!}A)^{-1}={}^{\mathrm t}(A^{-1}).$$

Comment: I believe the RHS of your second eqn should be $1_R$. (I tried to edit this in but the correction was less than 6 characters.)

Comment: @user474330: Perfectly right. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $B$ is an inverse of $A$ if $AB=BA=I$.

When we multiply $A^TB^{-1}$ with $B(A^T)^{-1}$ we get
$$A^TB^{-1}B(A^T)^{-1}=A^T(B^{-1}B)(A^T)^{-1}=A^TI(A^T)^{-1}=A^T(A^T)^{-1}=I$$
Doing the same operations and flipping the order shows that the inverse of $A^TB^{-1}$ is $B(A^T)^{-1}$.